# Websocket.onmessage isn't firing

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

I try to communicate between a Java WebsocketServer (https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket) with an a Webpage via a JS-WebSocket.

My JS-Websocket:

```
window.websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
window.websocket.onopen = () => {
    window.websocket.send("Hello")
}




window.websocket.onmmessage = function(event) {
    alert('Hi');

    console.log(event.data);
}
```

and my Java-Websocket-Server:

```java
package test;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;

public class testsocket extends WebSocketServer {


    private static int TCP_PORT = 9000;

    private Set<WebSocket> conns;

    public testsocket() throws UnknownHostException {
        super(new InetSocketAddress(TCP_PORT));
        conns = new HashSet<>();

    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake) {
        conns.add(conn);
        System.out.println("New connection from " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress().getAddress().getHostAddress());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
        System.out.println(message);

        String s2send = "hello";
        System.out.println(s2send);
        conn.send(s2send);


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        if (conn != null) {
            conns.remove(conn);
            // do some thing if required
        }

    }

}
```

So my Java-Websocket prints "Hello", so I can communicate from JS to Java, but on the other hand my Websocket is neither showing the alert nor printing in the console, so I assume onmessage isn't firing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure, your java ws server is working... Then

There is a typo!  the event listener should be `window.websocket.onmessage`. **NOT** `window.websocket.onmmessage`. Two "m"s :)

```
window.websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");
      window.websocket.onopen = () => {
        window.websocket.send("Hello");
      };

      window.websocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        alert("Hi");

        console.log(event.data);
      };
```